# Show a view in the home screen when home button is clicked from the app

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

During the video call in the applications like whatsapp, hike, etc.. when we press the home button, the remote video view gets rendered in a small box with the drag feature in the home screen. how it is handled. For my requirement, I must show a view in the home screen when home button is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is called Picture-in-picture mode. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Comment: That can be [PIP](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture) or a view which was drawn on Window from `Service` .

Comment: Thanks, will that work in below api 26?

Comment: @Goutham, no this wont work below API 26 (Android 8.0)

Comment: 1)
0
down vote
favorite
During the video call in the applications like whatsapp, hike, etc.. when we press the home button, the remote video view gets rendered in a small box with the drag feature in the home screen. how it is handled. - Via PIP mode as mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: 2) I must show a view in the home screen when home button is clicked. - I think this you can achieve with the help of the widgets in android.  Refer "https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview"

Comment: Goutham i was added my points as comments.